# Next row value in next column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to display next row value in the current row as next column in SQL Server?

**Mast** table

```
 ID  Name
 ---------
 1   XYZ
 2   abc
 3   MNO
```

**Detail** table

```
 ID  Date
 -------------
 1   1/1/2019
 1   1/2/2019
 2   2/2/2019
 2   3/3/2019
 2   3/4/2019
 3   2/2/2019
 3   4/2/2019
```

I need the result to look like this:

```
    ID  Date      Next Date
    ------------------------
    1   1/1/2019   1/2/2019
    1   1/2/2019   NULL
    2   2/2/2019   3/3/2019
    2   3/3/2019   3/4/2019
    2   3/4/2019   NULL
    3   2/2/2019   4/2/2019
    3   4/2/2019   NULL
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you shared **Mast** table.

Comment: Please provide the sql to create (and, ideally, populate) your table, to make it easier for the community to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Use `lead()` window analytic function

```
select ID, Date, lead(Date) over (partition by ID Order by Date) as Next_Date
  from Detail
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=dc2d980bcdf7fc2de3c6a016ff892a89)</kbd>